# Invalid Xpath 2 error for 'Click' selenium function

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have ran a test using Selenium IDE 2.3.0 and copied the Junit4/Remote control script into the Eclispe Classic 4.2.2 and started running my code as 'Junit4'.

I see the following error:

```
Invalid Xpath 2
```

The selenium command in Eclipse for Xpath is:

```
selenium.click("//input[@value='Search Equipment']");
```

I tried copying the Xpath using Firebug which was:

```
/html/body/section[2]/section/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/span/input
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: could you give the relevant part of the html too ?

Comment: The following is the html part copied from Selenium IDE: selenium.click("//input[@value='Search Equipment']");

Comment: Do I need to add the @type=submit in my xpath expression? i.e. selenium.click("//input[@value='Search Equipment']" & [@type= 'submit')

Comment: I believe @Babai was asking for the relevant part of the *page* html (not the Selenium IDE test).

Comment: Thanks Justin Ko.The page html can be find here : http://www.rbauction.com/ and the I'm working on the specific object 'Search equipment' and the html for 'Search equipment' is : <input type="submit" data-bp3value="Search Equipment" data-bp2value="Search Equipment" data-bp1value="Search Equipment" data-bp0value="Search Equipment" data-attrlist="bp0:value,bp1:value,bp2:value,bp3:value" value="Search Equipment" class="qa-auto-keyword-submit rba-button rba-btn-lvl-1 float-right rba-attr-trigger">

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, i understood that you need to click on the button "SearchEquipment".
So try with this xpath :

```
selenium.click("//span[@id= 'rba-keyword-submit']/input")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, you are right and I have to click on a button 'Search equipment'and I have used the xpath you provided but it's giving me the same error : Invalid Xpath 2

Comment: May be i can give one more try. Try this xpath :(

Answer (score 0):

start selenium record and enter some thing to ur textbox or if its a button click the button then click stop.you can get the correct xpath by going to target in the relevant step in selenium IDE.use last xpath.

Comment: One thing I have noticed which may be useful for resolving this issue. The actual selenium IDE Command generated when recording is : "Command = 'ClickAndWait' and target = //input[@value='Search Equipment'] and nothing in the "value" field coz it is just a click functionality. But after, when I change the html version to Java/Junit4/Remote control the "ClickAndWait" command changes to Only "Click" in the Junit Remote control code. This may be causing the issue I guess.

Comment: The wait command has been separated to the next line i.e. selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");